# GRUB overwritten Refind/Mac bootloader - Unable to boot

Tags: macos, keyboard, startup, efi, grub

Getting desperate here, need some help

background:
I have a late 2012 imac, running OS X 10.10
Also i had Xubuntu & OpenSuse running as secondary OSs

I was using refind & everything was rosy.
Recently i updated opensuse 13.1 to 13.2 through a live USB.
This basically zapped my refind & goes directly to GRUB2 bootloader.

Now GRUB shows me options (and advanced options) for Xubuntu & opensuse 13.1 only
Though 13.2 was installed as an upgrade, it doesn't show up.
13.1 doesn't boot either even after choosing it in GRUB.
Xubuntu loads without problems.

Now the issues am having:

- The Magic keyboard doesn't seem to be 'active' during the boot process, so pressing the 'option' key does not do anything.
- I also think that GRUB is not recognising any other bootable USBs either.

How do i go about restoring OS X or refind?
Refind website says it's recommended to install refind via OSX if running on a mac as installing via Linux will corrupt the partitions...further

is there any alternate to pressing 'option' during boot? 
(i have a normal USB keyboard connected)

Answer (score 3):

Update - i was able to solve this situation.
The simplest solutions evade at times.

In case someone else runs into this, what i did-
In the grub menu i was trying to see if i could do something in the command line interface..
Just typed exit & immediately i was popped back onto refind.
Immediately booted into OS X & reinstalled refind..

Comment: When I try "exit" in GRUB's command line it just says "command not found".